# iOS project with cocoapods builds perfectly in Xcode, but fails in Azure pipeline

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, cocoapods, cicd

The iOS project that am working on,builds perfectly in Xcode but fails to build in Azure pipeline. GoogleAppMeasurement and FirebaseAnalytics third-party frameworks are used and are
installed using cocoapods. The shell scripts in CP Embed pods Frameworks generate Target Support Files, during Pod installation, which the azure
pipeline is not able to access and hence throws error in the  Xcode build task.[image: Pipeline Screenshot][image: Error Screenshot]

Things that I tried below:-

1. Unchecked based on dependency
2. Reinstalling Pods and removing derived data
3. Changed Input file lists to input files and output file lists to output files
4. Adding #include Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner..xcconfig in the cconfig file.
5. Added Pods-COPD-frameworks.sh to project directory
6. Added "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = arm64; to Project
7. Added config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0' to Podfile
8. Added Shell Script in pipeline to execute Pod Install –Verbose
   [image: pod install with option]
   [image: Comparison of Screenshot of Pod Install –Verbose on Terminal with that from Azure]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your screenshot, when it runs in Azure, it looks like the PODS_ROOT environment variable is not set.